# Remove dupilcates query in INSERT SELECT statement

Tags: sql, subquery, insert-select, clockify

I have a query which is inserting data into Clockify Table from Task Table through INSERT SELECT statements.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[ClockifyAdd]  
 AS  
 BEGIN  
       insert into Clockify(ClockifyId,DurationInMinutes,Date)
         SELECT 
              ClockifyId
            , SUM(DATEDIFF(mi, CAST(StartTime AS datetime), CAST(EndTime AS 
               datetime))) AS DurationInMinutes
            , CAST(StartTime AS date) AS Date
        FROM Task
        GROUP BY
              ClockifyId
            , CAST(StartTime AS date)
END
```

The problem is while inserting into Clockify table I don't want to insert duplicates and put a check here. I have a stored procedure to remove duplicates but I want a better approach that while inserting there must be a check for duplicates and if there is a duplicate it must not insert. Please look image for better understanding
Thanks in advance for replying and taking out your precious time to address this issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4R2Q.png)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and your code is non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if value is already prensent uning a left join anche check for null value

```
insert into Clockify(ClockifyId,DurationInMinutes,Date)
     SELECT 
          Task.ClockifyId
        , SUM(DATEDIFF(mi, CAST(Task.StartTime AS datetime), CAST(Task.EndTime AS 
           datetime))) AS DurationInMinutes
        , CAST(Task.StartTime AS date) AS Date
    FROM Task
    LEFT JOIN Clockify 
        ON Task.ClockifyId = Clockify.ClockifyId 
            AND Task.Date = Clockify.Date
    WHERE Clockify.ClockifyId Is NULL
    GROUP BY
          Task-ClockifyId
        , CAST(Task.StartTime AS date)
```

Comment: Yes it is working, now I'am getting unique rows everytime. Thanks scaisEdge. Appreciated

Comment: Yes sure, I learned how to accept and I have accepted the answer. Thanks

Comment: ...@Syedibrahim  ...  .you comment seems weird

Comment: haha!!  I'am new to stackoverflow. Learning how to use it :p

Comment: what if I want to update the record if it exists in the above query.?

Comment: depend on the db you are really using  (sql is a query language not a db) anyway You could try using a constrain  .ON INSER UPDATE ..  or a separated  query base on an update and join  with the suibquery ..  for this you shoudl post a new question properly documented ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use not exists as follows:

```
 insert into Clockify(ClockifyId,DurationInMinutes,Date)
         select t.* from
          (SELECT 
              ClockifyId
            , SUM(DATEDIFF(mi, CAST(StartTime AS datetime), CAST(EndTime AS 
               datetime))) AS DurationInMinutes
            , CAST(StartTime AS date) AS Date
        FROM Task
        GROUP BY
              ClockifyId
            , CAST(StartTime AS date) ) t
     where not exists 
           (select 1 from Clockify c 
            where c.ClockifyId = t.ClockifyId
              and c.DurationInMinutes = t.DurationInMinutes
              and c.Date = t.Date) 
    -- remove the condition on column from here if you don't want to 
    -- consider column for finding duplicate
```

Comment: Thanks Popeye this query is also giving desired results. Appreciated